# How to add public key using ssh2_publickey_add

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I want to create a system that can login to SSH with PHP.

First,  run this command to generate the key:

```
$process = shell_exec("ssh-keygen -q -N '' -f $this->fullPath -C 'JY-Forge'");
```

Then I want to copy that public key to the server using `ssh2_publickey_add`.

Here is my code

```
$this->connection = ssh2_connect($param['server_host'], 22);
ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $param['superuser'], $param['superuser_password']);
$pkey = ssh2_publickey_init($this->connection);
$send = ssh2_publickey_add($pkey, 'ssh-rsa', $param['key'], false, array("comment" => "JY-Forge"));
```

But, when I run the program I got an error:

> ssh2_publickey_init(): Unable to initialize publickey subsystem(0)

I'm using virtualbox here, not a real server..

Did I forget something?

Comment: maybe you meant to use [ssh2_auth_pubkey_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php) if your goal is to `login to SSH with PHP` ?

Answer (score 0):

While there is indeed an [RFC 4819](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4819) for "public key" SSH subsystem, it's not widely adopted.

Notably, it's not supported by the most widespread SSH server, the OpenSSH. So you will hardly be able to use it.

The subsystem is for example [supported by Vandyke VShell (since 2.3)](https://www.vandyke.com/download/vshell/2.3/history_windows.txt).